# Acceso a widgets creados en un ciclo for Python

Tags: python-3.7

Defini una funcion para generar widgets en un ABM. Es un toplevel en el cual inserto los widgets que defini en un diccionario (Entries, Labels, Combobox). Lo genera perfectamente, pero cuando quiero insertar un valor en uno de los Entry (por ejemplo...), no se como llamar a ese widget...
Alguien podria ayudarme...
Muchas gracias.

```
widgets =  {"ent_Nombre_clase":StringVar(),
        "lab_Nombre_clase":StringVar(),
        "cbb_lista_dia_semana":StringVar(),
        "lab_Dia":StringVar(),
        "ent_Hora_inicio":StringVar(),
        "lab_Hora_inicio":StringVar(),
        "ent_Hora_finalizacion":StringVar(),
        "lab_Hora_finalizacion":StringVar(),
        "cbb_lista_ritmos":StringVar(),
        "lab_Ritmo":StringVar(),
        "cbb_lista_grupos":StringVar(),
        "lab_Grupo":StringVar(),
        "cbb_lista_profesores":StringVar(),
        "lab_Profesor":StringVar(),
        "ent_Costo":StringVar(),
        "lab_Costo":StringVar()}


def abm_clase():
    tl_clase = Toplevel(root)
    tl_clase.grab_set()
    tl_clase.title(f"ABM clases")
    tl_clase.config(bg=COLOR1)
    tl_clase.geometry("245x500+500+100")
    
    counter = 1
    for i in widgets:
        cur_name = i
        if cur_name[0:3] == "ent":
            cur_name = Entry(tl_clase, font = "verdana 14 bold", justify = CENTER, width = 17)
            cur_name.grid(row = counter, column = 0)
            counter +=1
        elif cur_name [0:3] == "lab":
            cur_name = Label(tl_clase, height=2, text = i[4:], bg = COLOR1, font = "Verdana 8", anchor = "ne", width = 34)
            cur_name.grid(row = counter, column = 0)
            counter +=1
        elif cur_name[0:3] == "cbb":
            cur_name = AutocompleteCombobox(tl_clase, width=20, justify = CENTER, font="Verdana 11 bold",completevalues = globals()[f"{i[4:]}"])
            cur_name['values'] = globals()[f"{i[4:]}"]
            cur_name.grid(row = counter, column = 0)
            counter +=1
        else:
            pass
```